# IOException occurs when clearing console window in resized state

Tags: c#, console, resize, ioexception

As the title says, when I resize my console window to a certain shape, an `IOException` will be thrown when calling `Console.Clear()`, and I'm not sure why. Here's my example code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; ;)
        {
            Console.Write(i++);
            Thread.Sleep(250);
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a nice little GIF to demonstrate how to reproduce this:

[image]

Now, I have no clue why this is happening, if it's supposed to happen, and let alone how to fix/prevent this. Can anyone explain? I'm very curious!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My console window wont let me go down to the 0 line high that yours does, so mine doesnt barf - the fact yours does would be the reason.

Comment: @BugFinder Just curious, what OS are you on?

Comment: I am on win 7..

Comment: @BugFinder I guess this might be because of win10 then.. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your are trying to Clear a console that has one dimension to 0. I guess that clear is trying to put the cursor on the top left position and as it can't, it throws that exception.

You can solve just adding a check before `Console.Clear`:

```
static void Main()
{
    for (int i = 0; ;)
    {
        Console.Write(i++);
        Thread.Sleep(250);
        if (Console.WindowHeight>0 && Console.WindowWidth>0)
            Console.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, hold on, I'll try to reproduce this with `Console.SetCursorPosition()` then.. EDIT: It seems you're right, it happens when setting the cursor pos to 0,0 manually too.. I'll accept this answer as my problem seems to be solved! Thanks :-)